# Mysql union exclude duplicate entry by row

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `date1` UNION SELECT * FROM `date2` ORDER BY (count1+count2) DESC
```

I need exclude duplicate entries by 'ID' column.

Can I do this with UNION?

**Update:**

table1

```
+---------+--------+
| id      | count1 |
+---------+--------+
| 112337  | 567    |
+----+-------------+
```

table2

```
+---------+--------+
| id      | count1 |
+---------+--------+
| 112337  | 565    |
+----+-------------+
```

I want to display only first 'id' data.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results so it is clear what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I have two tables 'date1' and 'date2'. Both of them have 'id' column. I want exclude duplicate 'id' in result.

Comment: What is going on here with the bizarre quoting around `date1` and `date2`? Do your table names have actual literal double quotes in them?

Comment: No tadman sorry) It is just copied from php code. Just table 'date1' and table 'date2'.

Comment: Tip: Unless your column names have unusual characters in them, or conflict with MySQL reserved keywords, you don't need to escape them like that.

Comment: Yes,you are right. Thanks tadman. But what about actual question? What is a simple way to exclude same 'id' from result?

Comment: Do you want to exclude, or combine? Normally you'd use `GROUP BY` to do that.

Comment: Exclude. I tried GROUP BY ID, but it doesn`t work.

Comment: Please provide a few rows of sample data and the expected result. Your question is not clear enough.

Comment: @the-implaner question updated.

Comment: This sounds like a case where the data needs to be normalized. e.g. one `date` table and identifier to identify the record type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT * FROM date1 
UNION
SELECT d2.* FROM date2 d2
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM date1 d1 WHERE d1.id = d2.id)
```

Also change to `UNION ALL`, which is more efficient, if you don't want to exclude duplicate rows or if there re no duplicate `id`s in each table.

Comment: I think it is good answer and it is accepted. But please explain this answer to other users who can have this issue. For exmaple what is d2.*, d2 and d2.id and etc.?

Comment: d2 and d1 are the aliases of the tables date2 and date1. In the subquery: `(SELECT 1 FROM date1 d1 WHERE d1.id = d2.id)` these aliases are used to qualify the 2 id columns each belonging to a different table.

Answer (score 0):

Using a union and wrapping it in a main query with aggregation may be what you want.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS T,T1;

CREATE TABLE T(ID INT, COUNT1 INT);
CREATE TABLE T1(ID INT, COUNT1 INT);

INSERT INTO T VALUES (1,567),(2,20);
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES(1,565),(3,20);

select tid ,
         max(case when tcount1 is not null then tcount1 else t1count1 end) cnt
from
(select id tid,count1 tcount1,null t1count1 from t
union
select  id tid,null tcount1,count1 from t1
) s
group by tid;

+------+------+
| tid  | cnt  |
+------+------+
|    1 |  567 |
|    2 |   20 |
|    3 |   20 |
+------+------+
3 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```